# MATCH in MYSQL 5.5.24 not working

Tags: mysql, database, wamp, wampserver

I am writing the following query :

select * from student where match(`name`,`middle name`) against('amar');

I am getting error as : The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes.

I am using mysql version 5.5.24 on wamp server.

How to solve this issue.
Thank you

Comment: on what engine did you create the table ? InnoDB or MyISAM ?

Comment: InnoDB

I got this using show table status command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before Mysql 5.6, full text search is supported by only myisam engine not innodb, it seems you are using innodb engine for this table.

Even it seems that you did not create full text index on table otherwise you will get error at that time also...

full text index is different from btree default index.

Comment: I changed the engine now but I am still getting the error , but slightly different

Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Comment: yes first you need to create full text index on table if you have changed it to myisam.

Comment: I will try to create it
Thank you very much for your reply it is helpful

Comment: Can you help me out how to change my column so that they work with FULLTEXT index

Comment: I used this syntax :

ALTER TABLE table ADD FULLTEXT index_name(name);

but when I add middlename it gives me error as :
Duplicate key index_name;

Comment: it should be either alter table mytable add fulltext idx_name(f_name) or it can be alter table mytable add fulltext idx_name(f_name,m_name);

Comment: if your field name is middle name means space between field name then enclosed it under "`".